# When can I consider "authorities" as a plural noun that has no singular form?

Tags: grammar

For example

> The authorities are advising drivers to avoid the area if at all possible.

Comment: When you work for them, or are shilling for them, and are providing them anonymous cover. Otherwise, name names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time it is found in the  plural. From [OALD, 4](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/authority?q=authority).

> [countable, usually plural] the people or an organization who have the power to make decisions or who have a particular area of responsibility in a country or region
> I have to report this to the authorities.
> The health authorities are investigating the problem.

Rarely enough, this word is used in the singular with the same meaning, as for instance in "[*local authority*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/local-authority?q=local+authority)" (Britain).

> the organization that is responsible for the government of an area in the UK

Once the term has been introduced in a text there is the possibility to do away with the adjective and to write merely "the authority", although you don't have to; apparently, even when two occurrences of the term are found in close proximity the adjective is almost always retained.

([ref. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Building_Regulations_in_Brief/RQxgAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+local+authority%22&pg=PA126&printsec=frontcover)) During the 42-day consultation period **the local authority** will serve a notice on adjoining owners or occupiers. The neighbour has a 21-day period in which to raise an objection with the local authority. **The authority** will take this objection into

([ref. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Deddf_Cartrefi_Symudol_Cymru_2013_Nodiad/F1rrdoodsy0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+local+authority%22&pg=RA1-PA4-IA1&printsec=frontcover)) When such works are ongoing **the local authority** can prohibit or restrict the movement of mobile homes on to the site . **The authority** may attach a condition to the licence so as to require the completion of the necessary work

([ref. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Anti_Social_Behaviour_Crime_and_Policing/xTlq5zK6OnMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+local+authority%22&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover)) Part 4 - Community protection Chapter 1 Community protection notices ( a ) **the local authority** that issued the community protection notice ; ( b ) if the community protection notice was not issued by **a local authority** , **the local authority** ( or , as the case may be, one of **the local authorities**...

The singular will be found also in other compounds such as the following.

> [the Highway Authority](https://www.councilclaims.co.uk/highway-authority-duties/)

Comment: The OP is asking about "authorities" as a plural-only noun.

Comment: @BillJ It seems to me that this is contained in the label "[countable, usually plural]". When you use "the authorities" in a general way, you can use only the plural, unless the entity so referred to has a name  (such and such Authority, for example "California High-Speed Rail Authority ") and then you can refer to it as  "the Authority". Isn't that so?

Comment: @LPH I think you are right. "Authority" as a singular and sometimes pluralised noun is different from "the authorities" as a plural-only noun. The singular noun in the plural still refers to specific entities such as "neighbouring local authorities" or "the authorities such as the OED all say...". The non-specific plural has more in common with "the powers that be", a nebulous set of influential institutions

Comment: @BoldBen There are two singular nouns (at least); as meaning organization entrusted power it does refer to entities such as "neighbouring local authorities", but not to the authorities in "the authorities such as the OED …", I think; in this latter case the noun is changed and means instead "experts". Yes, I think I can relate to this impression of "nebulous set of influential institutions" and I'm not sure it is entirely due to the inability of the reader to identify the particular governmental bodies referred to among quite a few of these there might be to choose from.

Comment: @LPH I think you're right in saying that there is more than one singular noun, I hadn't thought of it in that way, I was thinking that anyone or body that had any sort of authority was 'an authority' in that sense.When it comes to regulatory, legislative and supervisory body, let alone interpretive bodies and individuals such as High Court judges it would be impossible, I think. for anyone to list all those who had influence over a specific case. "The powers that be" then becomes a phrase which is a very useful shortcut, in spide of its dubious grammar.